# Passing a directory and file name variable that contains spaces from Foreach Loop to an Execute Process task

Tags: ssis

I have a Foreach File Enumerator that loops through all files in a folder, saving the directory and file name to a variable @NextFile.

Inside the Foreach, I have an Execute Process Task which is passed the variable @NextFile.

I pass the variable by selecting Edit on the Execute Task, Expressions->Arguments->@[User::NextFile].

This works fine if the file name has no spaces, but when there is a space, the String passed in will end where the first space appears.

Eg: if the directory name is `c:\files\file a.pdf`, the variable will be `c:\files\file`

I've tried to enclose NextFile in quotes "@[User::NextFile]" but then the variable is set to `"@[User::NextFile]"`

Comment: A silly question I know, but is your string variable that contains the file path long enough? Also what is returned if you include a Script Task as the first element in your For-Each loop with this line of logic `MsgBox(Dts.Variables("NextFile").Value.ToString)`. The script task also need to have "NextFile" entered in the "ReadOnlyVariables" box in the General dialogue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your expression look like:
`"\"" + @[User::Filename] + "\""`

[image: Expression]